# Is there a tool that helps me draw a venn diagram easily?

Tags: script, python, libraries, diagrams

For some reason I have to draw a lot of venn diagrams and I hope I can just specify the `sets` and its `elements` and it emits the right image. I do *not* care about the blazonry.

So is there any tool or script or libraries suitable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pyVenn is a python library that shoud help you: http://code.google.com/p/pyvenn/

an alternative would be [matplotlib-venn](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/matplotlib-venn), which the author [describes here](http://fouryears.eu/2012/10/13/venn-diagrams-in-python/). It supports multiple sets, but depends on matplotlib.

Comment: It seems that pyVenn can only support two sets:-(

Comment: then use matplotlib-venn, which depends on matplotlib

Comment: `matplotlib-venn` is what I need exactly, thx

Answer (score 1):

**Venn Diagram Maker by Creately**:

- Venn diagram templates to get started quickly
- Export Venn diagrams as image files or pdf files
- Easy styling options to add color and clarity to diagrams

http://creately.com/Draw-Venn-Diagrams-Online

**Grapholite** allows you to easier create a Venn charts by offering the following abilities:

- drawing tools and shape
- ability to work in online and offline modes; in and out of browser
- export to the most commonly used picture and document formats

http://grapholite.com/Diagrams/VennDiagrams

**Gliffy’s Venn diagrams**: Use one of the pre-prepared Venn diagram templates, or create your own using the extensive library of shapes and images. Draw, style, and align shapes and easily insert and format text using market-leading Venn diagram software.

And because Gliffy is collaborative online software, it’s easy to share the Venn diagrams you’ve created by inviting other users to Gliffy, exporting them as images or PDFs, or embedding them in your blogs and wikis.

http://www.gliffy.com/uses/venn-diagram-software-template/

Answer (score 0):

Excel includes this functionality. Microsoft's documentation for creating Venn diagrams is found here:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-a-venn-diagram-HA010335959.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are a few relevant options:

Lucidchart has a [Venn diagram](https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/examples/venn_diagram_maker) maker.  It provides a lot of flexibility but the tradeoff there is that it requires a bit more manual effort to get it sorted correctly.

matplotlib-venn is a Python package that is more scripted.

Answer (score 0):

I use the [venn diagram template](https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/examples/venn-diagram-template) from Lucidchart to draw mine.  It is super easy to use and integrates with google drive.

Answer (score 0):

This one is good for generating 2 or 3 sets, from real data
http://simbioinf.com/mcbc/applications/genevenn/genevenn.htm